# how to add component on button click in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I want to add a react component to the dom on button click. Here I have a simple function for it.

```
const addCargo = () => {
        const parentElement = document.getElementById("addCargoContainer");
        parentElement.insertBefore(<Cargo />, parentElement.children[2]);
    }
```

but this gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Is there a possible way to do this?

Comment: You probably want to be setting state instead.

Comment: `const {cargos, setCargos} = useState([<Cargo />])

 const addCargo = () => {
  setCargos([...cargos, <Cargo />])
 }`
Well I tried this but doesnt seem to be working too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will something like this work?

```
function Cargo() {
  return <div>cargo</div>
}

function Ship() {
  const [cargos, setCargos] = useState([])

  const handleAddCargo = () => {
    const newCargo = Date.now()
    setCargos(v => [...v, newCargo])
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>ship</h1>
      <button onClick={handleAddCargo}>add cargo</button>
      {cargos.map(() => <Cargo />)}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const [isCargoVisible,setIsCargoVisible] = useState(false);
return(
    <>
    <button onClick={()=>setIsCargoVisible(true)}>Hit me to add cargo div</button>
    {
      isCargoVisible ? (
        <div id='addCargoContainer'>
          {/* Your code inside */}
        </div>
       ) : null
    }
  </>
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).